# What implementations/uses of special methods ("magic methods") are bad practice in python?

Tags: python, interface-implementation

I'm designing a python module that interfaces with several parts of a simulation API (via windows dll). I would like to make full use of python so that the library is both clean and simple to use.

When implementing my own class to interface with a part of the API, I found myself wanting to implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` as accessors to the API's `getValue()` and `setValue()` methods. It provides a cleaner interface to the internal hex values within the simulation software, but is this bad practice or perhaps not pythonic?

Below is an example of what I would like to implement:

```
# Note that each word is identified by a unique integer and each has a
# settable/retrievable hex value within the simulation software.

class sim:
    ...
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        ''' check for valid key range (int)'''
        ''' else throw exception '''
        val = simAPI.getValue(key) # returns the value of the word at the key in the 
                                   # software, None on failure
        if val:
            return val
        '''else throw exception '''

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        ''' check for valid key range and value (int, int)'''
        ''' else throw exception '''

        if not simAPI.setValue(key, value): # sets the value of the word at the key in the 
        ''' throw exception'''              # software, None on failure

    ...
    ...
```

This would allow for:

```
Word = sim() 

Word[20] = 0x0003 # set word 20 to hex value 0x0003 in the simulation software

if Word[23] == 0x0005: # check if word 23 is equal to 0x0005 
    pass
```

and maybe with more development, slicing to set multiple words:

```
Word[1:5] = 0x0004 # set words 1-5 to 0x0004
```

Although I have described my specific case, I sincerely welcome a general discussion on what implementations/uses of special methods are bad practice.

In advance, thank you for your time in answering my question!

Comment: The design you describe looks pretty good to my eye.

Comment: This may not be appropriate for Stack Overflow, since it's asking for a "general discussion" rather than the solution to a particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily a bad practice.  The thing about getting and setting items is you only get one operation for them.  That is, there is only one syntax that lets you do `object[index]` with square brackets.  So the main thing is just to be sure that you really want to "use up" that syntax with the operation you're defining.

If in the SimAPI these `getValue` methods really do seem like an obvious choices -- that is, if `getValue` really gets *the* value and not just *a* value -- it seems fine.  What you want to avoid is picking a relatively random or non-special operation and giving it special status by making `__getitem__` access it.